# Why subtraction of functions does not necessarily result in subtraction of their big O functions

Tags: asymptotics

How can I show that if $d(n)$ is $O(f(n))$ and $e(n)$ is $O(g(n))$, then $d(n) - e(n)$ is not necessarily $O(f(n) - g(n))$.

Could someone explain it please?

Comment: Note that $n/2$ and $n$ are both $O(n)$ but $n-n/2=n/2$ is not $O(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $2f(n)$ is $O(f(n))$ for any function $f$.
Also, $f(n)$ is $O(f(n))$ as well.

If what you're saying was true, then $f(n)$ would be $O(0)$ for any function, which is very far from being true.